# Selenium WebDriver unable to find a very obvious tag when done through JAVA

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, automation, frontend

I am trying really hard (almost out of all the arrows in my arsenel) to find a very simple div through selenium and click on it.
Following is the div.

```
    <div ng-class="{toolbarButtonDisabled:svDisabled, toolbarButtonOpaque:svDisabled}" class="toolbarButton ng-isolate-scope" title="" ng-click="click($event)" single-click="onHandleView()" style="padding-left: 10px;padding-right: 10px;" image="images/dashboard.png" label="View Dashboard" sv-disabled="!onlyOneCustomDashboardSelected">
<img style="margin: 0 auto; display: block" ng-src="images/dashboard.png" src="images/dashboard.png">
<div class="labelDiv">
    <p style="white-space: nowrap; padding-bottom: 2px" class="ng-binding">View Dashboard</p>
</div>
</div>
```

following are the tricks I have already tried to find the element.

```
    getWebDriver().findElement(By.xpath("//img[@src='images/dashboard.png']")) ;
    getWebDriver().findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='labelDiv']//p[.='View Dashboard']"));
    getWebDriver().findElement(By.xpath("//div[@ng-src='images/dashboard.png']"));
```

All the above methods, I have also tried with css selectors
eg for the first one,

```
       getWebDriver().findElement(By.cssSelector("//img[src='images/dashboard.png']")) ;
```

So before clicking this element I am waiting for it, which is not giving any error but when i do a click it just doesn't click.

For clicking I have used all the three possible clicks that I know of :

```
    1) webdriverClick
    2) nativeClick
    3) javascriptExecutor click
```

Nothing seems to work.

This element clicks properly when I do it using firebug and do a

```
$($0).trigger('click') or $('.toolbarButton.ng-isolate-scope')[1].click();
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I found the solution. A hacky one though. The issue here as I analyzed is that, the DOM gets refreshed after a click which I make to get the above div visible. And once I click, Even though the above div is visible, it is not visible to selenium driver. The DOM in the driver does not get refreshed, while actually "visibly" I can see that being refreshed. So, I did some irrelevant action so that DOM gets refreshed. The question now is does selenium stores DOM in some cache ? and If yes how to explicitly refresh that cache.

Answer (score 0):

None of your xpath expressions reference the same `div` that's referenced by your working firebug call.  They reference an `img`, a `p` and a different `div`.

I think this call should work

```
getWebDriver().findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(@class,'ng-isolate-scope')]")) ;
```

Comment: Thanks Don for quick reply. But the point is, there is <p> and a <image> in the same div. which are all clickable and working from firebug call. The class which you have provided as solution, is too generic. There exists multiple web elements with that class in the dom. So , I tried the following        By.xpath("//div[contains(@class,'ng-isolate-scope')][contains(@label,'View Dashboard')]" but to no avail. Any other ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

Hi assuming that the text "View Dashboard" appears only once on the html page of your app, try the following, it should work:

```
getWebDriver().findElement(By.linkText("View Dashboard")).click();
```

UPDATES: 
Try the following, it should work this time using css selectors:

```
getWebDriver().findElement(By.cssSelector("div.toolbarButton.ng-isolate-scope div.labelDiv p")).click();
```

This should work this time!

Comment: Nope this is not working. I think the text should be in <a> tags for this to work. In this case it is in <p> tag. Thanks for the reply though.

Comment: Please see UPDATES above ! It should now work for you!! If the above doesn't work then simply try removing the `.ng-isolate-scope` class from the code above and keep the same code like this: getWebDriver().findElement(By.cssSelector("div.toolbarButton div.labelDiv p")).click();!

Comment: Thanks Pelican. I tried this. The problem with this is that there are multiple web elements with same style and this one selects the first one. The only thing that is making them unique is the text. Then I tried to get all the elements with the above style and click on the specified style using hard coded index as in getWebDriver().findElements(By.cssSelector("div.toolbarButton.ng-isolate-scope div.labelDiv p")).get(1).click(). Still no luck.